# Does the amount of overriden abstract class methods impact the concrete class creation time?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

So i'm interested in whether the amount of overridden methods impact performance and creation time of concrete class in C#. And also whether deep hierarchy(abstract class A> abstract class B > ... > concret class Z) impact has some impact. And if yes, then why?
The question is only for educational purposes, and for better understanding on how abstract classes work under the hood in C#

Comment: No, the compiler knows what to ultimately produce as your methods are still determined at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The type hierarchy will be called in the order from most `base type -> most derived`. You can see it by debugging.

So question can be reformulated to *is it expensive operation to create an instance of object in CLR*. [According to this profile, it is not!](https://ayende.com/blog/4811/performance-numbers-in-the-pub) CLR creates `7,715,305` for `1` second.

So, creation of object is cheap, but Garbage Collection is not. [Be careful of premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/202970).